# Yoroi from Daedalus and Ledger nano

Tags: daedalus, yoroi, ledger

I'm sorry if this has been answered elsewhere, I couldn't find it specifically.
If I have been using Daedalus with a Ledger Nano and I download Yoroi on Brave browser (I want to get involved in Sundaeswap), what would I need to do to see the funds in there? Do I need to enter the seed phrase? I heard it's generally not a good idea to be typing that in and you'd prefer to avoid it. Is that true? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Ledger, you can just connect to it in Yoroi, no need to restore with your seed phrase or create a new wallet.

With that said, you never should enter your Ledger phrase anywhere except for a *Ledger device that you own.* Meaning if your device breaks, buy a new one to restore to.

I hope this helps!

[image: Yoroi HW Support]

Comment: Wonderful, thank you. I have it set up now. One quick question, when I was exporting the public key on my ledger, it said something about Byron? Why would Byron have anything to do with it?

Comment: My best guess is you have a Byron era wallet on the ledger. How long ago did you get the wallet?

Comment: I just checked my emails and the receipt for my ledger was Feb 5th. So it probably arrived and I had it set up by Mid Feb. I can't remember when we went to Shelley.

Comment: Oh weird, the hard fork was July 29th, 2020, so I wouldn't think it would be a Byron wallet. But you can tell by what the address begins with if it is addr it is shelly.

Comment: Yeah all mine begin with addr. I tried on a new browser (last time was Firefox, this time Brave). I got the same results - after choosing Ledger Nano S - it pops up a grey box on screen about USB etc. Then on the Nano screen it says Export public key. I click both buttons at once - then I get nothing new on Yoroi. I choose Ledger Nano S again and this time it is saying Byron Account #1 and a bunch of letters and numbers and slashes I wrote down. By the way, it is transacting fine in AdaLite.

Comment: When I connected to ADALite it says "Export 6 public keys?" and I choose the tick and it works. I have been looking at the advanced tab and it says Keys: Byron Extended Public Key, Shelley Extended Public Key, Staking Key, Reward Address and Staking Key Hash Hex. I also tried Nami and it works but it didn't have any funds. It turns out that only uses the Account #2 while Daedalus had things setup to use Account #1. Yoroi just seems to have an issue with an old Daedalus Shelley wallet so I'll just use Nami I guess.

Comment: Thanks for the update. That is very odd. I have a Ledger as well, so I'll try playing with it and seeing if I have a similar experience.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to create a separate wallet in Yoroi and transfer some small test funds to carry out the test. **Never enter seed phrase in a website.**,**Never enter seed phrase in a website.** Yoroi is a browser extension. In case you decide to migrate to Yoroi in the future you may need to enter the seed phrase. But please do not do it unless you are quite clear on what you are doing. You can refer to this video [Restoring a Daedalus Software Wallet in Yoroi](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V6j43PdLzqs)

Just to repeat it is recommended that you create a new wallet in Yoroi and use it for testing.